# package "plink" is not available

Tags: r

Hello
When I installing plink, I get the messages. 
(My version 3.1.3)
In the site,  http://healthstat.snu.ac.kr/CRAN/index.html
I can not find the "plink". 
How can I use "plink"?
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `repos` argument.

```
> install.packages("plink", repos = "http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror")
Installing package into ‘C:/.../R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘statmod’

trying URL 'http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/statmod_1.4.17.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155890 bytes (152 KB)
opened URL
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/plink_1.3-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 854055 bytes (834 KB)
opened URL
downloaded 834 KB

package ‘statmod’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘plink’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\...\Local\Temp\RtmpIzfu4y\downloaded_packages
> library(plink)
Loading required package: lattice
```

Comment: @hwiinLEE if my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as the correct answer (check the tick under the score at the upper left corner of the answer).